# Test a Spring Controller with JUnit that depends of Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-security

I have a Spring Application and I am building `JUnit` tests to test a certain `Controller`.

The problem is that inside the `Controller` I call this code:

```
final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
final String userName = authentication.getName();
```

In other words, I need to authenticate before calling this `Controller`. I wrote a `JUnit` test with this code:

```
private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void getPageTest() throws Exception{
        final ProcessFileController controller = new ProcessFileController();
        mockMvc = standaloneSetup(controller).build();

    mockMvc.perform(get(URI.create("/processFile.html")).sessionAttr("freeTrialEmailAddress", "")).andExpect(view().name("processFile"));
        }
```

And when I run it gives me a `NullPointerException` right on the `final String userName = authentication.getName();` because my `authentication` is `null` since I did not login.

The question is: Is there a way to mock the authentication? All ideas are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you doing that manually instead of using `@AuthenticationPrincipal`?

Comment: chrylis, the architecture was not designed to use the  `@AuthenticationPrincipal`, I need an idea, a way to deal with that with the current architecture that I have right now. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you would use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` but if that isn't an option you need to setup the `SecurityContext` with an `Authentication` instance that will then be available in the test.

You could you a static method in a helper class to do this.

```
public static void setupSecurityContext(String username, String password, String... groups)
{
  List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
  for (String group : groups)
  {
    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(group));
  }

  UserDetails user = new UserDetails(username, password, authorities);
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password);
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token);
}
```

Then in the test you can simply call

`SecurityHelper.setupSecurityContext("user", "password", "g1", "g2");`

Comment: It will be nice to reset the `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(token)` after the test, to make the tests independent. As this SecurityContextHolder is a singleton, you are sharing the same information among all unit tests.

Comment: @Dherik you could set to null in a \@After method.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'm only warning this because it's a common problem when people use Singleton on tests and can cause weird problems during the tests

Answer (score 5):

Spring Security version 4 introduced some neat improvements regarding this.

First make sure you have the testing framework in the classpath for tests, with Maven it looks like:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Useful imports:

```java
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.setup.SecurityMockMvcConfigurers.*;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.*;
```

Test setup:

```java
mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(applicationContext).apply(springSecurity()).build();
```

(I think you need to the WebApplicationContext rather than a single controller.)

Then the test something like:

```java
mockMvc.perform(get(...).with(user("username").roles("USER"))).andExpect(...);
```

Comment: How the User is created? can you post the code snippet.